# Probability $P(X=Y)$

Tags: probability, random-variables

2 people independently toss a coin with probability p for "heads" until they get "heads". X - number of tosses of 1'st person, Y - number of tosses of 2'nd person.
Find P(X=Y).

Comment: In order to get responses that suit your needs, please include **in the body of the question** your own thoughts, the effort made so far, and the specific difficulties that got you stuck.

Comment: **Hint:** $Pr(X=Y) = \sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty Pr(X=k,Y=k)$ and by the independence assumption is $\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty Pr(X=k)Pr(Y=k)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As has been remarked, one can solve this by summing a Geometric Series.  It may, however, be useful to see a different approach. After all, in situations with more branching the Geometric Series method either fails or becomes needlessly complex.

let $\Psi$ be the answer.  We consider the result of the first (double) toss.  We note that either we have a win (probability $p^2$)  or a loss ($2p(1-p)$) or the game restarts, ($(1-p)^2$).  It follows that $$\Psi=p^2\times 1 +2p(1-p)\times 0 +(1-p)^2\times \Psi\implies \boxed {\Psi= \frac {p^2}{2p-p^2}=\frac p{2-p}}$$

We remark that, when $p=\frac 12$, this evaluates to $\frac 13$ as expected.

As further sanity checks note that it gives the correct answer at the extremes $p=0,1$ and that $\Psi\in [0,1]$ for $p\in [0,1]$.

As a technical remark:  This method supposed that $\Psi$ exists, which is not obvious.  As a computational matter one can just assume existence...to justify it one can remark that the series involved converges without the need to evaluate it.

Answer (score 2):

Probability of match on first flips:

$$M_1 = P(X_1=H, Y_1=H) = p^2$$

Probability of match on second flips *given that there was not a match on the first flips*:

$$M_2 = P(X_2=H, Y_2=H)P({\rm not}\ M_1)= p^2 (1 - p^2)$$

Can you continue and then sum them up?

Clearly (by symmetry) the number of *H* from either player will be the same once the game ends... but how can we estimate that number?

On each "failed" turn, the probability there is exactly one *H* rolled is $2 p (1-p)$.  (See why?)  We do not need to count the cases when there are zero heads (doesn't contribute) or two heads (doesn't occur).

So now you know how many (single) heads will appear (on average) up to the terminating flips.  Divide that number of heads by $2$ to compute the expected number of heads for *each* of the players.

Answer (score 0):

The probability  that their first successes are simultaneously is $$P(X=Y)=\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty \left((1-p)^2 \right)^{k-1} p^2=\sum\limits_{m=0}^\infty \left((1-p)^2 \right)^{m} p^2$$ Geometric distribution with probability of $p^2$.

Using the closed formula for the [geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Formula) with $r=(1-p)^2$ we obtain $$P(X=Y)=\frac{p}{2-p}$$